# Delay of a custom designed FA

Tags: integrated-circuit

The documentation about transistor delay presents a couple of picoseconds.
An AND gate of several transistors could be made to be about 3XTransistor delay - 10-20 Picoseconds (theoretically).
When searching the WWW I found the following data - CMOS: 0.1 nanoseconds. A custom FA was quoted as 0.5 nanoseconds.
I wonder why the delays are longer than anticipated by the data of the components.
What is the shortest delay of a FA implemented in 7nm technology?